# Interpretaciones de "delante de" y "detrás de" según los objetos en la escena

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones, adverbios, locuciones

Esto de tener hijos hace que tengas que volver a aprender multitud de conceptos. El ejemplo más reciente es el siguiente:

Imaginemos que estamos en una posición determinada de la calle. Vemos un árbol a lo lejos. Y resulta que entre el árbol y nosotros hay un coche del que no vemos muchos detalles. A priori sin saber nada más el árbol está "detrás del coche" ("detrás" porque en la línea de visión desde nosotros al árbol, este está detrás del coche).

Pero ahora resulta que nos acercamos, nos fijamos, y el coche está puesto con el morro mirando hacia el árbol. Para nosotros el árbol ahora está "delante del coche" ("delante" porque está "en la parte delantera del coche"). Pero mi hijo sigue diciendo que está "detrás del coche" porque sigue aplicando la lógica anterior con independencia de "hacia donde esté mirando el coche".

Así pues, tenemos un árbol de Schrödinger que puede estar al mismo tiempo delante y detrás del coche. La primera pregunta es: ¿cómo se puede justificar esta dualidad según las definiciones de "[delante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C61cg3i)" y "[detrás](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DahefUx)" en el DLE?

Ahora bien, si el coche fuera una caja, entonces las dudas se despejan y el árbol estaría indiscutiblemente "detrás de la caja", nunca "delante". La segunda pregunta (y siguientes) es: ¿en el uso de "delante" y "detrás" en estos casos, prevalece siempre en el lenguaje (a la hora de expresar su posición) el que el objeto intermedio tenga una parte delantera y una trasera, más que la posición del objeto con respecto a nuestra línea de visión? ¿Por qué "detrás del coche" se interpreta siempre como "en la parte trasera del coche" y no como "detrás según nuestra línea de visión"? ¿Cómo se puede expresar en español este concepto sin incurrir en ambigüedades?

Comment: este es un problema muy similar al de "¿mi izquierda o tu izquierda?" según yo lo veo, a ver que responde la gente.

Comment: Creo que aunque sea una caja que no tiene partes diferenciadas depende del punto de referencia que elijamos sigue siendo ambiguo. El árbol puede estar delante o detrás de la caja. **Delante** si sigo la línea de mi visión: yo → caja → árbol. **Detrás** si tomo el árbol como referencia: árbol → caja → yo

Comment: @walen en cuyo caso están en frente el uno del otro, no?

Comment: @BrianH. De acuerdo.  ¡Escribe una respuesta! // Charlie, supongo que tu hijo viaja en el asiento de atrás del coche, así que tiene súper clara la orientación del coche -- hocico para adelante, cajuela para atrás. // Video chistoso sobre el malentendido de la derecha y la izquierda y cómo cambian según el punto de vista: https://youtu.be/ioiLvMyyl7U

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En mi opinión la definición del DLE para las palabras "delante" y "detrás" es muy ambigua ya que no da mucho detalle para definir qué está "detrás" y qué está "delante", esto se debe a que, como explicaré mas adelante, La posición es un concepto relativo, veamos las definiciones que da el DLE para estas palabras:

> **detrás**
>
> 1. adv. En la parte posterior, o con posterioridad de lugar, o en sitio delante del cual está alguien o algo.
>
> **delante**
>
> 1. adv. Con prioridad de lugar, en la parte anterior o en sitio detrás del cual hay alguien o algo.

Como podemos ver en la misma definición de cada palabra, **"detrás"** es estar en un sitio **"delante"** del cual está alguien o algo y **"delante"** es estar un sitio **"detrás"** del cual está alguien o algo, esta definicion se puede entender mas claramente desde un punto de vista matematico/físico lo cual procederé a hacer mas adelante.

**vamos por puntos:**

---

**A priori sin saber nada más el árbol está "detrás del coche" ("detrás" porque en la línea de visión desde nosotros al árbol, este está detrás del coche).**

El árbol según la linea de vision del observador puede estar tanto "detrás" como "delante" del coche, depende del punto de referencia que se utilice para darle posición a los objetos, esto se puede entender mas claramente utilizando una [Recta Numérica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recta_num%C3%A9rica) imaginaria en el piso para darle un valor numérico a la posición de cada objeto, e.g:

[image: RECT1]

Cómo podemos ver en este ejemplo el árbol se encuentra en la posición `1` y el carro en la posición `2` según la recta numérica, ya definida la posición de cada uno de los objetos nos hace falta definir con que criterio vamos a evaluar la ubicación de cada uno:

**Criterio 1**

- Viéndolo de la misma forma que en una carrera, en la que el que va en
  la posición `1` va **adelante** de todos, el árbol está adelante del
  carro

**Criterio 2**

- Viéndolo según la [Magnitud (matemática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitud_(matem%C3%A1tica)) de los números, el numero `2` es mayor que el numero `1` `(2>1)` por ende se podría decir que el carro esta adelante del árbol

---

**Ahora bien, si el coche fuera una caja, entonces las dudas se despejan y el árbol estaría indiscutiblemente "detrás de la caja", nunca "delante"**

No se puede decir que el árbol está indiscutiblemente "detrás de la caja" ya que esto es relativo, me explico:

Como tu dijiste, tomando el morro del carro como referencia, el árbol estaría adelante del coche ya que el coche esta "mirando" en esa dirección, ahora supongamos que en lugar del coche hay una caja tal como tu lo planteas, imaginemos que la caja tiene dibujados unos ojos en uno de sus lados, si los ojos están "mirando" hacia el árbol se podría decir respecto a donde está "mirando" la caja el árbol está **delante** de la caja, si los ojos están mirando hacia el lado contrario del árbol se podría decir que el árbol está **detrás** de la caja.

---

**¿Por qué "detrás del coche" se interpreta siempre como "en la parte trasera del coche" y no como "detrás según nuestra línea de visión"? ¿Cómo se puede expresar en español este concepto sin incurrir en ambigüedades?**

Me parece que esto tiene que ver mas con algo cultural que con el lenguaje, ya que por costumbre para la gente la parte trasera del coche es la que queda a espaldas del conductor, donde usualmente está el baúl y el escape.

---

**¿en el uso de "delante" y "detrás" en estos casos, prevalece siempre en el lenguaje (a la hora de expresar su posición) el que el objeto intermedio tenga una parte delantera y una trasera, más que la posición del objeto con respecto a nuestra línea de visión?**

La posición es un conceptos relativos, para hablar de la posicion de un objeto tenemos que referirnos a un sistema de referencia o referencial particular escogida por el observador ya que no hay un punto de referencia absoluto en el universo. Diferentes observadores pueden utilizar referenciales distintos, es importante relacionar las observaciones realizadas por cada uno. Un objeto estático cambia su posición **respecto** al observador si este se mueve de lugar o cambia su sistema referencial.

Esto se puede visualizar mas fácilmente con un ejemplo gráfico utilizando un plano cartesiano y dos observadores, tomemos el mismo ejemplo del carro y el árbol, para este ejemplo vamos a representar el **Árbol** con un **circulo verde** y el **Carro** con un **cuadrado rojo**, los observadores los vamos a representar con flechas de diferentes colores, hacia donde esté apuntando la flecha será hacia **adelante** y el lado contrario sera hacia **atrás** (Esto es muy importante ya que este sera el sistema de referencia para todos los ejemplos), Para todas las situaciones vamos tomar al **Árbol** y el **Carro** como el centro del plano cartesiano `(0,0)` y los observadores se desplazaran respecto a estos ( Para mas información sobre sistemas de referencia puedes ingresar al siguiente [link](https://www.fisicalab.com/apartado/movimiento-sistemas-referencia#contenidos)), ahora bien, se pueden realizar infinidad de ejemplos pero creo que con 5 es suficiente, empecemos con los ejemplos:

**Situación 1**

[image: SIT1]

- El Árbol y el carro están **adelante** de los dos observadores

**Situación 2**

[image: SIT2]

- El árbol y el carro están **atrás** del observador amarillo
- El árbol y el carro están **adelante** del observador azul

**Situación 3**

[image: SIT3]

- El Árbol y el carro están **adelante** de los dos observadores
- Para el observador amarillo el carro está **adelante** del árbol
- Para el observador azul el árbol está **adelante** del carro

**Situación 4**

[image: SIT4]

- Para el observador amarillo el carro está **adelante** de él y el carro está **atrás** de él
- Para el observador azul el carro y el árbol están **atrás** de el
- Para el observador azul el árbol está **atrás** del carro

**Situación 5**

[image: SIT5]

en este caso ambos observadores se encuentran en el mismo lugar, pero la posicion relativa del árbol y el carro es diferente para cada uno:

- Para el observador amarillo el carro y el árbol están **adelante** de él
- Para el observador amarillo el árbol esta **adelante** del carro
- Para el observador azul el carro y el árbol están **atrás** de él
- Para el observador azul el árbol esta **atrás** del carro

Answer (score 4):

- **¿Cómo se puede justificar esta dualidad según las definiciones de "delante" y "detrás" en el DLE?**

El DLE no dice que el punto de vista a aplicar sea necesariamente el de quien habla o escribe; sólo dice: "**delante**: *con prioridad de lugar, en la parte anterior o en sitio detrás del cual hay alguien o algo*".
Y claro, el problema es que dentro de esa acepción encontramos distintos criterios:

- con prioridad de lugar;
- en la parte anterior; o
- en sitio detrás del cual hay alguien o algo.

Lo cual hace que el uso pueda interpretarse de distintas maneras.
Como bien explicas más adelante en tu pregunta, **cuando dices "el árbol está *detrás* del coche" defines un orden o prioridad**, siguiendo una línea hacia tu posición: lo más cercano en esa línea está delante (más prioridad), y lo más lejano detrás (menos prioridad). Eso corresponde al primer criterio.
Por otro lado, **al decir "el árbol está delante del coche", te basas en cambio en las partes anterior y posterior del propio coche**: el árbol está en la parte anterior del coche (en el morro). Eso corresponde al segundo criterio.
Ambas afirmaciones son correctas, lo que cambia es el criterio usado.

- **¿En el uso de "delante" y "detrás" en estos casos, prevalece siempre (...) que el objeto intermedio tenga una parte delantera y una trasera, más que la posición del objeto con respecto a nuestra línea de visión?**

No, no tiene por qué. Depende de a qué le quieras dar relevancia. Yo hay veces que sigo diciendo "detrás del coche" aunque el objeto esté en el morro, cuando lo importante es mi punto de visión y no el coche: por ejemplo, jugando al escondite :D

- **¿Por qué "detrás del coche" se interpreta siempre como "en la parte trasera del coche" y no como "detrás según nuestra línea de visión"?**

"Siempre" es demasiado categórico en este caso; depende del uso que quiera hacer la persona que habla. Ver punto anterior. Lo que pasa es que normalmente, cuando decimos "detrás del coche" es porque estamos hablando de la posición de algo respecto del coche.

- **¿Cómo se puede expresar en español este concepto sin incurrir en ambigüedades?**

Puedes usar *"el coche está [**antes**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=2oDyn3W) del árbol"* y *"el árbol está [**después**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=DQBHjWr) del coche"*. Estos adverbios comparten con "delante" el criterio de "prioridad", pero eliminan el de "parte anterior/posterior", con lo cual se elimina el equívoco.
También puedes usar *"el árbol está **pasado** el coche"*, usando el participio del verbo [pasar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=S33P1kX) para dar a entender que, en un camino imaginario tú - coche - árbol, tienes que pasar el coche para llegar hasta el árbol.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, felicidades, porque la pregunta es realmente magnífica, y me ha tenido pensando un buen rato jaja.

Dicho esto, como hombre de ciencias me veo "obligado a intervenir". Simplemente como un pequeño aporte a las respuestas de los demás.

Tal como yo lo veo, `el problema es similar al asunto de la relatividad entre observadores`, más que al asunto de derecha-izquierda.

Todos sabemos que "el movimiento es relativo", lo cual no significa nada místico ni etéreo, ni es un drama, sino que simplemente es que "depende del sistema de referencia (que en adelante escribiré como SR). En principio tenemos libertad para escoger el sistema de referencia.

Ahora bien, ¿qué es un SR? pues es tan simple como un punto arbitrario al que se le asigna el origen de coordenadas, es decir, un origen. Sin embargo, hay algo más que usualmente se obvia: es el origen... ¡ y unos ejes!

Físicamente, fijar un SR es fijar unos ejes. Comunmente se habla a veces de "un observador", pero no tiene por qué ser una persona; un SR son "unos ejes" escogidos a voluntad.

Ya termino con el rollo. Adonde quiero llegar es que, una caja es simétrica, por lo tanto hay una ambigüedad insalvable para escoger los ejes. Esto hace que pensemos en la caja como un objeto, y decimos que "el árbol está detrás de la caja", es decir, que con respecto a nosotros, la posición de la caja es menor que la del árbol.

Sin embargo, un coche tiene en sí mismo unos ejes asociados (delante, detrás, derecha, izquierda). Esto invita al hablante a pensar en el coche como SR. Cuando tú dices "el árbol está delante del coche", estás tomando como SR el coche, porque sus ejes invitan a hacerlo. La posición del árbol es positiva respecto al origen en el coche.

> Si el SR lo fijamos donde nos encontramos nosotros y el coche es un objeto, entonces el árbol está detrás del coche. Sin embargo, si nos abstraemos de que nosotros estamos presentes y pensamos en el coche como SR, entonces el árbol está delante del coche.

Sobre el cómo solucionarlo, que supongo que es también importante, la ambigüedad yo la solventaría utilizando la locución preposicional "con respecto a".

> El árbol está detrás del coche; delante respecto del coche".

Answer (score 0):

Si el objeto en cuestion **no tiene anterior o posterior**, entonces la posicion depende del observador: el objeto eclipsado estará detrás y el objeto eclipsante estará delante.

Si el objeto en cuestión **tiene anterior o posterior**, entonces se establecerá la referencia en cuanto a la relación entre los objetos observados: si yo estoy detrás de ti, nadie puede venir a decirme que estoy delante de ti, ¿o si?

Fuentes: yo mismo.